# How can i change the value of checkbox upon change

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I would like to change the value of the checkbox, but failed with the following code.

```js
$("input:checkbox").on("change", function () {
    if (this.checked == true) {
        this.val("1");
    }
    else {
        this.val("0");
    }
});
```

I not sure why it is no responds without the code, which it should've the "checked" when I'm calling this element, but no. So i will need to add a value field manually.

```
<input class="c-switch-input" type="checkbox" name="pk_{{$d['id']}}" value="{{$d['status']}}">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing jQuery and DOM incorrectly

EITHER

```
this.value = "1";
```

OR

```
$(this).val("1")
```

But use a ternary:

```js
$("input:checkbox").on("change", function () {
   this.value = this.checked  ? "1" : "0";
   console.log(this.value)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" />
```